# Matching Unicode letter characters in PCRE/PHP

Tags: php, regex, unicode, pcre, character-properties

I'm trying to write a reasonably permissive validator for names in PHP, and my first attempt consists of the following pattern:

```
// unicode letters, apostrophe, hyphen, space
$namePattern = "/^([\\p{L}'\\- ])+$/";
```

This is eventually passed to a call to `preg_match()`. As far as I can tell, this works with your vanilla ASCII alphabet, but seems to trip up on spicier characters like Ă or 张.

Is there something wrong with the pattern itself? Perhaps I'm expecting `\p{L}` to do more work than I think it does?

Or does it have something to do with the way input is being passed in? I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I did make sure to specify a UTF8 encoding on the form page.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think the problem is much simpler than that: You forgot to specify the `u` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). The Unicode character properties are [only available in UTF-8 mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

Your regex should be:

```
// unicode letters, apostrophe, hyphen, space
$namePattern = '/^[-\' \p{L}]+$/u';
```

Comment: Weird. Try `$namePattern = '/^[\pL]$/';
$a = '张';
var_dump(preg_match($namePattern, $a));
$a = '张1';
var_dump(preg_match($namePattern, $a));` and variants. It does work for me without u. PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7

Comment: @chx: Gives me `int(0)`. Your file probably isn't encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: It is, I have used the utf8ToUnicode routine showed in my answer to verify the codepoints in my file.

Comment: @chx: In that case, I don't know. It doesn't work for me without the modifier, but it works with it. As PHP doesn't have proper multibyte support, issues with encoding are common.

Comment: Yep, as simple as adding the `u`. Follow-up question: what does the `u` indicate, precisely? Since my pattern without the `u` still matched ASCII, I'm guessing it tells the regex something about the nature of the input string, rather than the pattern itself.

Comment: @Jeff Lee: It indicates, that the string should be handled as an UTF-8 string. I.e.: A UTF-8 character may consist of sever bytes. Normally PCRE would match every single byte against your regex. But in UTF-8 mode it will combine those bytes and matches these ;)

Comment: +1, for completion, another way to turn on unicode properties in this pattern: `(*UTF)(*UCP)^[-\' \p{L}]+$` (see [PCRE's Special Start-of-Pattern Modifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#pcre))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace Unicode `old pattern` with `new pattern` you should write:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bold pattern\b/u', 'new pattern', $text);
```

So the key here is `u` modifier

**Note** : Your server `php version` shoud be at least `PHP 4.3.5`

as mentioned here [php.net | Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
>        This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This
>   modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP
>   4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

Thanks `AgreeOrNot` who give me that key here [preg_replace match whole word in arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898521/preg-replace-match-whole-word-in-arabic)

I tried it and it worked in localhost but when I try it in remote server it didn't work, then I found that php.net start use `u` modifier in PHP 4.3.5. , I upgrade php version and it works

Its important to know that this method is very helpful for Arabic users (عربي) because - as I believe - unicode is the best encode for arabic language, and replacement will not work if you don't use the `u` modifier, see next example it should work with you

`$text = preg_replace('/\bمرحبا بك\b/u', 'NEW', $text);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your life would be a lot easier if you'd use single apostrophes instead of double quotes when writing these -- you need only one backslash. Second, combining marks `\pM` should also be included. If you find a character not matched please find out its Unicode code point and then you can use http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/ to figure out where it is. I found http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/ an invaluable tool when doing debugging with UTF-8 properties (don't forget to convert to hex before trying to look up: `array_map('dechex', utf8ToUnicode($text))`).

For example, Ă turns out to be http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0102/index.htm and to be in Lu and so L should match it and it does match for me. The other character is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5f20/index.htm and is also isLetter and indeed matches for me. Do you have the Unicode character tables compiled in?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else looking here and not getting this to work, please note that `/u` will not produce consistent result with Unicode scripts across different PHP versions.

See example: https://3v4l.org/4hB9e

Related: [Incosistent regex result for Thai characters across different PHP version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173877/incosistent-regex-result-for-thai-characters-across-different-php-version)

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php preg_match('/[a-zığüşöç]/u',$title)  ?>
```