# preg_replace match whole word in arabic

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to do

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bمرحبا بك\b/', 'NEW', $text);
```

but its not working, i think this function does not support arabic

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: have you tried [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? It should work, too.

Answer (score 5):

If your text is in UTF-8 encoding, append the ['u' modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to your regex pattern for Unicode support.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bمرحبا بك\b/u', 'NEW', $text);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. At least not for me.

Comment: Is your text in UTF-8 encoding? If yes, can you post the original value of `$text`?

Comment: I used the text that is used in the regex. so مرحبا بك

Comment: Is it possible that you mixed up `\b` with `\B`? Because `\b` is for word character.

Comment: No copy pasted your code and pasted in php interactive shell. If it's working for the question asker though, it's good. I don't need this to work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook you for the OP.

Comment: not working for me too, its ignore the word

Comment: **Important Note** : Your server php version shoud be at least PHP 4.3.5 check this: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php @AgreeOrNot thank you very much for giving me the key to start solve that problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't add a `\b` at the end of your regex. The matching should work fine when you change your code into this:

```
 $text = preg_replace('/\bمرحبا بك/', 'NEW', $text);
```

You cannot use `\b` at the end as well since there is a space in the word(s) you're trying to match. `\b` fails to match anything when there is a non word-character in the part you're trying to match.

Comment: not get the whole word if its a part of an other word it will replace too

Comment: @علاءمحمد, I updated my answer with an extra explanation about why that's not possible with what you're currently trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

Just take [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). No need for regex.

```
$text = 'hello bمرحبا بك world';
echo str_replace('bمرحبا بك', 'NEW', $text);
```

Comment: and can you tell me how this will work, مرحبا بكم