# PCRE is compiled with utf-8 support but doesn't support it

Tags: php, pcre

While the result of `pcretest -C` in my server says that pcre supports utf8, but the following code always returns false even if I enter a matching pattern, and seems that it doesn't recognize utf-8 characters:

```
   $pattern = '/^\x{06F0}?\x{06F9}\d{9}$/u';
   if (!preg_match($pattern, $value)) { // $value is a function parameter
      return false;
   }
   return true;
```

Output of `pcretest -C`:

```
PCRE version 7.8 2008-09-05
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

PHP version: 5.3.2

This code works as expected in my localhost.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Same results in localhost for pcretest -C?

Comment: @JensonMJohn In localhost pcretest command is not found.

Comment: I didn get the solution, but juz check whthr it's relatd to ur problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983392/matching-unicode-letter-characters-in-pcre-php

Answer (score 2):

Works here (note `html_entity_decode`'s charset default changed to UTF-8 in PHP 5.4):

```
$ cat a.php
<?php
$pattern = '/^\x{06F0}?\x{06F9}\d{9}$/u';
var_dump(preg_match($pattern, html_entity_decode('&#x6F9;123456789')));
$ php a.php 
int(1)
```

Note that PHP, by default, doesn't use the system PCRE library (though many distros, for obvious reasons, use the system PCRE library). Type `php -i` and look for the PCRE section to get more information about the version your binaries use.

Comment: Thanks. it seems that the problem is with html_entity_decode function. I tested your code in localhost and production server. in localhost it returns `int(1)` but in the server it returns `int(0)`.
My code is a part of a drupal module. and drupal uses `html_entity_decode` function. Is there any way to solve the problem without updating php?

Comment: @hpn There's no "problem" with `html_entity_decode`, all that's changed is its default value for the third argument. If you do `html_entity_decode('&#x6F9;123456789', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` the behavior should be the same in PHP 5.3 and 5.4.