# filter persian words in RegEx

Tags: php, regex

i want to filer a persian words in php
i want to replace `خ` with `خیابان`
here my code but it dident work
its my code

```
preg_replace('/\bخ\b/'
,'خیابان'
,'خ جردن-بالاتر از اسفندیار-خ سعیدی-نبش مهرداد');
```

but my output is zero!!!!

Comment: If I run this I get "خ جردن-بالاتر از اسفندیار-خ سعیدی-نبش مهرداد".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching Unicode letter characters in PCRE/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983392/matching-unicode-letter-characters-in-pcre-php)

Comment: The given code does not output anything, so "zero" looks like a pretty strange result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should use the unicode modifier in your regex:

```php
<?php
$regex = '/\bخ\b/u';
$repl = 'خیابان';
$text = 'خ جردن-بالاتر از اسفندیار-خ سعیدی-نبش مهرداد';

echo preg_replace($regex, $repl , $text);
```

Comment: thank you
can you explain me whats the ```u``` work???