# Incosistent regex result for Thai characters across different PHP version

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match, thai

String is considered valid if contains `alphanumeric` and `_` and `-` and `Thai characters`, otherwise invalid. Characters like `.` or `@` are invalid.

Based on the PHP documentation, the following regex should be working:

```
^[\w\-\p{Thai}]+$
```

It even seems to work as expected here: https://regex101.com/r/rfwjng/1

However doesn't work in my PHP code, nor working here: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/wDf

```
private function containsInvalidCharacters($value) {
    return !preg_match('/^[\w\-\p{Thai}]+$/', $value);
}
```

---

Update 1:

To clarify if I do `/u` at the end, it starts matching unwanted characters on my local machine. Although that seems to work on the referenced link (as suggested in the comment.)

Update 2:

Issue resolved when using `'/^[\wก-๙-]+$/u'`. For some reason `\p{Thai}` was not giving consistent results across PHP versions. See here: https://3v4l.org/4hB9e

Comment: You need `u` flag, `'/^[\w\-\p{Thai}]+$/u'`. Also, it is safer to move `-` to the end, ``'/^[\w\p{Thai}-]+$/u'``

Comment: No, `u` works [as expected](https://3v4l.org/4hB9e).

Comment: `u` is for UTF-8. If it doesn't work for you, what encoding are you using?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I checked and it's UTF-8 too when I do, from the same screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/e4w1Kyc 

Comment: Thai person swing by, this is what I use for Thai character /[ก-๙]+/ https://regex101.com/r/sDPcjH/1

Comment: Apparently I just noticed, in this same link https://3v4l.org/4hB9e, the results are varying based on PHP versions. So the results are not consistent. Thanks Doppio for sharing that - that seems to solve the issue. Maybe post as an answer?